# .NET Standard & Databases (ADO.Net)

Tags: ado.net, ssms, .net-standard

Is a ADO.Net Library the way to go with connecting to the DB In .NET Standard or is there any new standards with .NET Standard that I should be aware of?  (Logically, I figured if there is a Standard on handling libraries then ADO.Net should be phased out for a .NET Standard practice or at least be engulfed under .NET Standard to create concept/branding consistency)

Comment: I'm not aware of any standard. I personally use ADO.Net for small applications and EF for the largest ones. But if you don't know T-SQL then go with EF.